# How do I put a condition inside a filter in power BI (DAX)?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am just getting started with Power BI and am struggling to create a measure. I am trying to count the sum of my column "Repartition", but with some filters.

Here is my current measure:

```
Nb_Actifs = CALCULATE (SUM(PAIE[Repartition]), FILTER(PAIE, PAIE[REMUNERABLE] = "Oui"), IF(PAIE[PROFIL]="CC", FILTER(PAIE, PAIE[Taux_Contractuel]<> 0)))
```

The filters that I put before my IF statement are the ones that I want to apply to all rows. The ones after the statement are the filters that I only want to apply to the rows where the condition PAIE[PROFIL]="CC" is met.

However, I get this error message: "A function 'FILTER' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed."

From what I understand I need to replace the IF function by a filter, but since there are several filters already I get confused as to how to do that in Power BI.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some logic within your filter to catch all the conditions you need to return:

```
Nb_Actifs = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( PAIE[Repartition] ), 
        FILTER ( 
            PAIE, 
            PAIE[REMUNERABLE] = "Oui" && (( PAIE[PROFIL] = "CC" && PAIE[Taux_Contractuel] <> 0 ) || PAIE[PROFIL] <> "CC" )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's very clear !

Answer (score 0):

I think a [SUMX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/sumx-function-dax) function would be more appropriate here. You would also want to put all logic into a single FILTER. Try

```
Nb_Actifs = 
    SUMX(
        FILTER(
            PAIE, 
            PAIE[REMUNERABLE] = "Oui" && 
                (
                    (PAIE[PROFIL] = "CC" && PAIE[Taux_Contractuel] <> 0) || 
                    (PAIE[PROFIL] <> "CC")
                )
        ), 
        PAIE[Repartition]
    )
```

Regardless of whether you use SUMX or not, putting all of your logic into a single FILTER with corresponding logic would solve your conditional filter problem.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I got 2 different answers with different methods and both seem to work, it really helps me understand the methodology !

Comment: @ALar Glad to hear it! Since your question was answered would you mind marking one of the answers as the "accepted solution" (green checkmark to the left of the answer) and maybe upvoting both answers? This is helpful for those with similar questions.

Comment: done ! I think I'm too recent to slack overflow for the upvote to show up but the checkmark does.